# How to make passenger and rvm work together?

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, rvm, passenger

I've had `rvm` installed beforehand. And I decided to install passenger from a package ([nginx-full and passenger](https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger/dists/squeeze/)) and would like to use the `ruby` installed with `rvm`. But somehow it doesn't work. Here's the test `sinatra` app I'm using (`~yuri/a1/app.rb`):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  "Hello and Goodbye"
end
```

~yuri/a1/config.ru:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

require './app.rb'
run Sinatra::Application
```

nginx.conf:

```
http {
    ...
    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
        # the paths in the above file point out to debian repository's ruby version
    server {
        server_name a1;
        root   /home/yuri/a1;
        access_log   /var/log/nginx/a1-access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/a1-error.log;
        passenger_enabled   on;
        passenger_ruby   /home/yuri/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p385@a1/ruby;
    }
}
```

But when I do `w3m http://a1` `access.log` says:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2013:21:14:58 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 403 168 "-" "w3m/0.5.2+cvs-1.1027"
```

and `error.log`:

```
2013/09/12 21:14:58 [error] 27622#0: *1 directory index of "/home/yuri/tr/" is forbidden, client: 127.0.0.1, server: tr, request: "GET / HTTP/1.0", host: "a1"
```

The app works if I run it as follows: `rvm ruby-1.9.3-p385@a1 && ruby app.rb`.

Is there a way to track down what's happening there? Or how to make it work?

Comment: What do you see in your errors.log? Also, have you checked whether /home/yuri is accessible by www-data, the user that Nginx runs as?

Comment: I've specified what I see in `errors.log`: directory index errors. And yes, `www-data` can read files in `/home/yuri/a1` (that's the user `nginx` runs as).

Comment: Not /home/yuri/a1, /home/yuri. *All* parent directories must *also* be accessible. Have you checked that too?

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Your 'root' must point to the 'public' directory.

Comment: @Hongli Is it `passenger`'s requirement? Or maybe `rack`'s one?

Comment: It's Passenger requirement. The documentation states that you *must* point the root to the 'public' directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`passenger` expects application directories to have a certain [layout](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app). Particularly, `config.ru` must reside up one level relative to the document root. That is:

/etc/nignx/nginx.conf:

```
...
http {
    ...
    passenger_root   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    server {
        server_name a1;
        root   /home/yuri/a1/public;
        access_log   /var/log/nginx/a1-access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/a1-error.log;
        passenger_ruby   /home/yuri/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p385@a1/ruby;
        passenger_enabled   on;
    }
}
```

~yuri/a1/app.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

~yuri/a1/config.ru:

```
require './app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

And:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3-p385
...
$ rvm --create use 1.9.3-p385@a1
...
$ curl http://a1
Hello World!
```

Comment: Your comment is a life-saver! Thank you! I wish the official RVM documentation is as helpful as your comment.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through setting up passenger 4.0.17 on Ubuntu Precise using the apt approach.

Here is what worked for me.

In the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
    passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
    passenger_ruby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.0.0-p247/ruby;
```

Try moving the passenger_ruby to outside of the server block.

Good Luck